# Testing an object's state at save

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, tdd, mocking, rhino-mocks

I'm looking to write unit tests for a method such as this one:

```
public override bool ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(string username, string password, string newPasswordQuestion, string newPasswordAnswer)
{
    ISPMembershipUserDao userDao = GetISPMembershipUserDao();

    if (ValidateUser(username, password))
    {
        SPMembershipUser user = userDao.GetUserByUserName(username);

        user.PasswordQuestion = newPasswordQuestion;
        user.PasswordAnswer = newPasswordAnswer;

        userDao.Save(user);

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

It's a fairly straight-forward method to test. I'm using the Rhino Mocks framework. But one aspect has me questioning myself. I stub the DAO object and its save method, and I'm wondering how deeply I should test that user object that is passed to the save method. Should I assert that *every* property of that object is as I expect it to be? Or should I only assert that the PasswordQuestion and PasswordAnswer properites have the correct values? The former seems right to me, as I should make sure that *only* those two properties have been modified, and the others haven't been touched.

I was hoping some people could give their opinions on this. Is there a rule of thumb or pattern to keep in mind for these types of situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning: personal opinion ahead**

Ok, now that that's out of the way.... for me, it comes down to what I need to do to feel that my code properly implements the needed logic.  In this case?  I'd have two test cases:

- Dealing with ValidateUser returning false

  - Should return false
  - Save should not have been called
- Dealing with ValidateUser returning true

  - Should return true
  - Save should have been called

    - Object passed to save has the modified question and answer
    - No checks of other properties on user object

However, if/when I got a bug filed that affected this part of the code, I'd add whatever (initially failing) tests were needed to cover the bug, fix the bug, and leave the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's so easy to set up a constraint here, why not test it to ensure there are no side-effects to your method?

```
stubbedUserDao.AssertWasCalled(x => x.Save(null), o => {
        o.IgnoreArguments();
        o.Constraints(Property.AllPropertiesMatch(expectedMatchingUser));
    });
```